# Can you port a SP map to a SMP server and vice versa?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to turn a Minecraft **single player** map **into** **multi-player** server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20692/is-it-possible-to-turn-a-minecraft-single-player-map-into-multi-player-server)
>   [How do I copy a Minecraft **multi-player** (SMP) map **to single-player**?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18190/how-do-i-copy-a-minecraft-multi-player-smp-map-to-single-player)

Is it possible to have a map in single player and port it into your server for SMP and vice versa ?

If so how ?

Comment: Yeah could be a dupe :S But it only ask from SMP to SP and I was wondering if you could make a map in single player a upload it into the SMP server too.

Comment: Damn Raven you're truly on my case tonite. I voted for you :(

Comment: :( It's not personal! I'm on chat if you want to talk about it, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the "Mods and Texture Packs" menu inside MineCraft, click on "Open Texture Pack Folder".  Go up one folder and down into the "saves" folder.  That is where all your saved SP worlds are.  Each world is one folder.

On a server, it generates a folder with the world data **which is (effectively) identical to any of your saved games.**  This folder it stores in the directory it runs from.

Simply copy and paste.

Comment: I will try to copy / paste and check if it's working. If so... + 15 for you, if not, look behind you :D

Comment: I do it on my own server all the time to troubleshoot problems in SP.  I'm fairly confidant that it will work.  :)  Like anything though, it you put stuff in the wrong places, it won't work.